# Getting balanceOf in real time?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, bsc

My application runs a while loop to check the balance amount of a token using the standard balanceOf function call. Nevertheless, it takes a couple of seconds for it to fetch an updated balance, how could I fetch balance in real time?

```
def check_liquidity(self, token_address, check):
   if check == 1:  
       self.token_contract = self.fetch_token_contract(token_address)
   token_balance = self.token_contract.functions.balanceOf(Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_address)).call()


   return token_balance


check = 1

while True:
   liq_check = time.time()
   liquidity = self.check_liquidity(contract_inputs["path"][1], check)
   liq_check_time = time.time() - liq_check
   liq_check_time = round(liq_check_time, 4)
   print(liquidity, liq_check_time)
   check += 1
```

So every iteration of the loop checks for the token balance, but it takes around 20 to 30 checks (Around 3/4 seconds) to update the balance of the token. I'm using QuickNode.

Comment: It should not take that long. Can you give more details on your setup? What node services do you use?

Comment: Sure thing, let me edit my question

Comment: Done and done, I hope I'm more clear now!

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what's the issue. For me, making a call on a remote node only takes a couple of ms. However, I am not familiar with web3.py and Quicknode.

Comment: The call does work and it returns me a value of the balance. What I want mean is that on the subsequent calls, the balance will be the same, hence its not updated until a couple of seconds

Comment: If a transaction changes the balance of an address, this transaction has to be picked up by a miner and mined first, which would take a couple of seconds. Only after it has been mined will the call to balanceOf be changed. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not firing up transactions, I'm executing the balanceOf function on contract addresses to check liquidity. Is this a good way to do so?

Comment: balanceOf checks the number of a particular token an address has. This number will only change if the address has less or more tokens (following a transfer, for instance). If there is no transfer, the balanceOf will stay the same.